# Paging file doesn't work right

Tags: pagefile

Every time I logon to my computer (Acer Aspire 5315-Windows Vista) I immediately get a message that System is low on memory. It isn't. Every day I have to go in and try to change the paging file. I follow the instructions but mine doesn't work right so it can take up to 1/2 hour. My computer has the currently allotted size of 256. I can't find out how to increase that size permanently so every day I have to waste time. Please can someone tell me how to change it permanently??? Or just how to get it to change easily. I have lots of RAM-if someone could just tell me how to force my computer to use it that would help a lot. thanks